# How to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{2k+1}{1+e^{\pi\left(2k+1\right)}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got to this series while solving an integral by contour, I checked the result of the series with Mathematica and it is $\dfrac{1}{24}$, which gives the correct result of the integral.
The problem is that I even no idea how to show that the series converges to that result.

I tried to rewrite it as a well-known converging series (like a geometric series) or to use the definition (limit of partial sums), but I couldn't manage to do either.

If it can be of any use, the series can also be written as (it won't compute with Mathematica):
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(2k+1\right)\left(1-\tanh\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(2k+1\right)\right)\right)$$
having used the following equality
$$1-\tanh\left(x\right)=\dfrac{2}{1+e^{2x}}$$

Comment: What's the integral?

Comment: @RandomVariable Most definitely, thank you very much. I couldn't find that question due to how the series was written.

Comment: @gist076923 The integral is $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x\sin x}{\cos x\cosh x}$

I saw it in a video, but they didn't solve it with a contour integral. The result should be $2\pi^2$ multiplied by the series in the title.